# Как вывести переменную из объекта, который находится в List?

Tags: java, list, объекты

Есть список "байкеров" типа List.
Каждый байкер это объект у которого есть поля типа String: Имя, Размер, Вещь.

Что сделал:

1. Создал списки имен,размеров и вещей, наполнил их, соответственно: именами, размерами, вещами

2. В цикле от 1 до 3, создал 3 новых объекта "biker" 
(Human biker = new Human(name,size,item);),
   где каждому из списка добавлял имя, размер, вещь. 
В этом же цикле поместил каждый объект в список байкеров "bikersList".

```
//наполняем список с именами
namesList.add("Bill");
namesList.add("Jhon");
namesList.add("Nathan");

//наполняем список размеров одежды
sizesList.add("L");
sizesList.add("S");
sizesList.add("XL");

//наполняем список вещей
itemsList.add("Beer");
itemsList.add("Cards");
itemsList.add("Shotgun");

for(int i=0;i<3;i++){ //создаем ,байкеров в цикле и помещаем их в список
            String name = (String) namesList.get(i);//кастуем элемент массива в строковую переменую
            String size = (String) sizesList.get(i);//кастуем элемент массива в строковую переменую
            String item = (String) itemsList.get(i);//кастуем элемент массива в строковую переменую
            Human biker = new Human(name,size,item);
            System.out.println("\nИмя байкера: " + biker.getName() + "\nРазмер одежды: " + biker.getSize() + "\nВещь: " +biker.getItem());
            bikersList.add(biker);
        }
```

Теперь мне нужно будет в цикле получать имена, размеры, вещи из каждого объеката "байкер", 
чтобы найти нужного (нужный размер и вещь).

 А вот как это сделать, ума не приложу.

 В цикле могу только получить объект "байкер" из списка

```
System.out.println(bikersList.get(i));
```

И он выводит белеберду типа **"terminator.Human@66a29884"**, где **"terminator"** это просто название **package**.

А как из объекта получить, например переменную "**name**"? 
Кстати в классе **Human** есть метод отдающий имя **getName()** - он возвращает переменную "**name**" из объекта.

Comment: >Могу только получить объект Human;
>В классе Human есть метод getName();
А как же получить name? Этот вопрос уровня мстителей

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(bikersList.get(i).getName());
```

а чтобы не писал белеберду, надо переопределить метод `toString()` в вашем классе Human примерно так

```
public class Human {
    //fields, getters, setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Biker{ " +
            "name: " + name +
            "size: " + size +
            "item: " + item +
            "}";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`bikersList.get(i)` вернет объект байкера из списка, и к этому объекту можно сразу обратится вызвав нужное поле, например: `System.out.println(bikersList.get(i).getName())`;

Вы почти правильно все сделали, но вообще можно делать примерно так как ниже написано :) На мой взгляд это удобнее. Надеюсь более менее понятно, если что то нужно уточнить, пишите, с радостью помогу!

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 2. Создадим к примеру трех Байкеров
        Biker one = new Biker("BikerOne", "XL", "ItemOne");
        Biker two = new Biker("BikerTwo", "M", "ItemTwo");
        Biker three = new Biker("BikerThree", "L", "ItemThree");

        // 3. Добавим их в список, мы же со списком работаетм :)
        List<Biker> bikers = Arrays.asList(one, two, three);

        // 4. Выведем в консоль весь список (тут нам поможет переопределенный метод toSting())
        System.out.println("All Bikers: ");
        bikers.forEach(System.out::println);

        // 5. А теперь выведем только тех байкеров из списка, у ноторых размер одежды XL
        System.out.println("Bikers with XL size: ");
        bikers.stream()
                .filter(biker -> "XL".equals(biker.getSize))
                .forEach(System.out::println);

        // 6. А теперь выведем в консоль только имена Байкеров, без остальных полей
        System.out.println("Bikers names: ");
        bikers.forEach(biker -> System.out.println(biker.getName()));
    }
}

// 1. Для начала опишем клас Байкер
class Biker {
    // У класса есть поля
    private String name;
    private String size;
    private String item;

    // Методы достука к ним
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(String size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(String item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    // Конструктор
    public Biker(String name, String size, String item) {
        this.name = name;
        this.size = size;
        this.item = item;
    }

    // Для удобства вывода в консоль, переопределяем метод так как нам удобно
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + name +
                " Size: " + size +
                " Item: " + item;
    }
}
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
All Bikers: 
Name: BikerOne Size: XL Item: ItemOne
Name: BikerTwo Size: M Item: ItemTwo
Name: BikerThree Size: L Item: ItemThree

Bikers with XL size: 
Name: BikerOne Size: XL Item: ItemOne

Bikers names: 
BikerOne
BikerTwo
BikerThree
```